# sending message to printk buffer from user space -- not working

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Actually i want my driver messages to reach my terminal for debugging purpose. So i just try to check by following below link.

I refred following link :--
http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing

I am using a ubuntu in side vmplayer virtual machine. Ubuntu is running in terminal mode inside virtual machine. 
I am trying to send some message to kernel printk buffer, buts echo command fails.

klog demon is also running i confirmed with following command .

```
ps aux | grep klogd
```

Cat command on proc printk entry :---

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4 4 1 7
```

run echo command :---

```
#sudo echo "<1>Writing critical printk messages from userspace" >/dev/kmsg
```

But i am not able to get the message on the terminal. I am getting following error when runs above command :--

```
-bash: /dev/kmsg: Permission denied
```

Please suggest how to print on console ?

my actual requirement is to ... send messages of printk() in my driver ... directly to my console. I am just testing here from my console that messages of low priority reaches console or not .

how this post is right then .. ?
[linux kprint messages on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972155/linux-kprint-messages-on-console)

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

The error is because the shell is the thing trying to write to `/dev/kmsg` (via the redirect), and it is not being run with `sudo`.  Also, by default `echo` is usually a shell builtin, not a binary that can executed in another process, though that's kind of irrelevant here.  The right way to do this is

```
echo "blah" | sudo tee /dev/kmsg
```

`tee` is a command that copies stdin to a file and stdout.  It's called `tee` because it's like a T-shaped pipe in a pipeline.

Comment: this will work ... sudo bash -c 'echo "<1>Writing critical printk messages from userspace" >/dev/kmsg'

Comment: On most systems, echo is also an executable at /bin/echo; it doesn't work because the shell, running as the original user before sudo, is responsible for redirection.